# Create a soap endpoint in spring boot with a custom URL

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap

I create the SOAP endpoint in my spring boot project

```
@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);

        return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/project/soap/*");
    }

    @Bean(name="CollaborationMessageService")
    public Wsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition() {
        SimpleWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new SimpleWsdl11Definition();
        wsdl11Definition.setWsdl(new ClassPathResource("/META-INF/wsdl/oracle/CollaborationMessageService.wsdl"));

        return wsdl11Definition;
    }
}
```

The endpoint is accessible in using below URL:-
http://localhost:8080/project/soap/CollaborationMessageService.wsdl

I want endpoint URL to be like:- 
http://localhost:8080/project/soap/CollaborationMessageService?wsdl

is there any possible way to make these changes?